# Escape characters with python json

Tags: python, json, escaping, python-3.6

I have a string that contains escape characters and I can't find a way to escape them with `json.loads()`

```
json_string = '{"field1" : "\A1\A2\A3"}'
data = json.loads(json_string)

# code to update data values

json.dump(data, out_file, indent = 4)
```

If I leave it as is, `json.loads()` throws `Invalid \escape` error because `\A` is not a valid escape sequence and I'm on board with that. So I've tried escaping the escape characters with `json_string.replace('\\', '\\\\')` but then I end up with double backslashes in my out_file `"\\A1\\A2\\A3"`. How do I write the original string `"\A1\A2\A3"` to my `out_file`? I've tried raw string, escaping escape characters, but the only things that's escaping is a solution.

Comment: Are you saying you're receiving invalid JSON from some source? And you're trying to programatically fix it? Or are you writing that string yourself somewhere and you're trying to get the quotes and backslashes right?

Comment: Not exactly. More like I was given a file with a bunch of json strings, some of which contain backslashes that get evaluated as invalid escape chars. Need to manipulate some of the data but also need to keep everything else as is, even if the strings are technically invalid. Just wondering if there is a way to preserve these strings even if they would break the next component that tries to consume them.